# How to install Image::Magick in perl version 5.18

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I need to install Image::Magick module in a machine and the credentials are below:

`Windows Version - 7`

`Perl Version 5.18`

Also I have tried so many ways like `cpan` `ppm` and also copied the module and directly pasted in the `c:\perl\lib\ and c:\perl\site\lib` and unfortunately no luck.

> In cpan installed

Running install for module 'Image::Magick'
Running make for J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.89-1.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\J\JC\JCRISTY\PerlMagick-6.89-1.tar.gz ok
./PerlMagick-6.89/
./PerlMagick-6.89/check.sh
./PerlMagick-6.89/Makefile.old
./PerlMagick-6.89/Makefile.nt
./PerlMagick-6.89/check.sh.in
./PerlMagick-6.89/demo/
./PerlMagick-6.89/demo/README
............
./PerlMagick-6.89/t/bzlib/read.t
./PerlMagick-6.89/t/input.fits
./PerlMagick-6.89/Makefile.PL
./PerlMagick-6.89/Makefile.PL.in
./PerlMagick-6.89/MANIFEST.SKIP
./PerlMagick-6.89/Makefile.am
./PerlMagick-6.89/Magick.xs
./PerlMagick-6.89/check

CPAN.pm: Building J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.89-1.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Image::Magick
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.89-1.tar.gz
[31m  C:\Perl\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

> ################################## WARNING! ####################
> It seems that you are trying to install Perl::Magick on a MS Wi
> perl + gcc compiler (e.g. strawberry perl), however we cannot f
> binaries installed on your system.

> Please check the following prerequisites:
>
> 1. You need to have installed ImageMagick Windows binaries from
>    https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows
> 2. We only support dynamic (DLL) ImageMagick binaries
>    note: it is not possible to mix 32/64-bit binaries of perl a
> 3. During installation select that you want to install ImageMag
>    development files (libraries+headers)
> 4. You also need to have ImageMagick's directory in your PATH
>    note: we are checking the presence of convert.exe and/or ide
> 5. You might need Visual C++ Redistributable Package installed
>    see instructions on ImageMagick's Binary Release webpage
>
> We are gonna continue, but chances for successful build are ver
> ################################################################
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lMagickCore
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lmoldname
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lkernel32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -luser32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lgdi32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lwinspool
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lcomdlg32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -ladvapi32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lshell32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lole32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -loleaut32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lnetapi32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -luuid
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lws2_32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lmpr
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lwinmm
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lversion
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lodbc32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lodbccp32
> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lcomctl32
> to undefined at C:/Perl/lib/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 1198.
> C:\Perl\bin\dmake.exe: *** [pm_to_blib] Error 2
> Failed during this command:
> JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.89-1.tar.gz             : make NO
> cpan> exit
> Lockfile removed.

After Installation the error displays as:

> D:>perl -wc test.pl
> Can't locate Image/Magick.pm in @INC (you may need to install the  >Image::Magick module) (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at test.pl line 2.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 2.

It would be appreciated if someone could suggest the way to close this.

Comment: there are some devel libraries that are required in advance IIRC, but can't remember which ones. Perhaps if you showed the error message(s) you are receiving, it may trigger something. It was a few months ago I ran into this.

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer about what "no luck" means. What (exactly) have you tried? What (exactly) unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: @DaveCross: Please check I have updated my question.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Your error message are text. Please post them as text.

Comment: @Dave Cross: Yes I will correct in this future.

Comment: Why not correct it now?

Comment: @DaveCross: Modified my Question

Comment: Many of those messages are clearly cut off - "It seems that you are trying to install Perl::Magick on a MS Wi...", " however we cannot f...", "it is not possible to mix 32/64-bit binaries of perl a ...", "chances for successful build are ver ...". If you can't take the time to check that you have given us all of the information, then why would we want to put in any effort to help you?

Comment: Also, the points 1 to 5 just underneath the "WARNING" message give you plenty of stuff to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

The Perl library Image::Magick is a wrapper around a C library called ImageMagick. You can't install the Perl library if the C library is not installed first. That's why your attempted `cpan` installation gave all of those "No library found" errors.

You can download the Windows version of ImageMagick from [the project's web site](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php). Once you have installed that, you can try to install the Perl library again.

Did you read the errors that you got from `cpan`? I'm really not sure why, after getting a message saying "install seems impossible" you would try running a test program!

Comment: That's why I  asked why I couldn't able to install this module.

Comment: @Dave Cross: Already I have installed the program. `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16`

Comment: The image of your error messages is incomplete and hard to read. If you post the complete text of those error messages then someone might want to help you.

Comment: @DaveCross cross: Modified my Question.